# Where did Lydia go?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is Lydia's home?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39257/where-is-lydias-home)

I recently went to a watchtower and met this girl Illia to help her kill her mom with Lydia. I thought she was cute so i told lydia we would part ways and followed Illia. Lydia told me that she'll be home if i need her and she is carrying a bunch of my expensive things, which i forgot she was carrying. I searched my breezehome and dragonsreach for her but i couldnt find her. Where could she be?

Answer (score 1):

Lydia should be either in Breezehome or Dragonsreach, I can't quite remember since I last played about 7 months ago. But it does take a while before she reappears back there; I assume it's due to travel time for Lydia. I think if you wait a while, she should be back. You could try the wait command, which I believe is the <kbd>T</kbd> key.